# Sitecore license on Deployment

Tags: sitecore

I've deployed my Sitecore project to the server and Im receiving the error

> Required license is missing: Runtime  Description: An unhandled
>   exception occurred .....
>
> Exception Details: Sitecore.SecurityModel.License.LicenseException:
>   Required license is missing: Runtime

Do I need to download and install the Sitecore CMS Setup and enter the license key in that on the server ? I was expecting it all to be contained within the file structure of the web site.

PS/ Exscuse the fact that this is a pretty simple question - extremely pushed for time. Many thanks,

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The Sitecore license file is an XML file that is located in your `\Data` folder by default.  It is also named "license.xml" by default.  You should have a reference to this file in your web.config file:

```xml
  <!--  LICENSE
        This value define the physical location of the license file.
        Can be site path (ex. /folder/...) or absolute (ex. c:\folder\...)
  -->
  <setting name="LicenseFile" value="$(dataFolder)/license.xml" />
```

If your site is working in another environment but not your deployment environment, ensure that your path for the `\Data` folder is the same on this server. Change the path of the `dataFolder` variable if the path is different:

```xml
<sc.variable name="dataFolder" value="D:\<YOUR_PATH_HERE>\Data" />
```

Hope this helps.